# Extract Rotation and Scale from 3x3 Matrix

Tags: math, matrix, 3d

I work on a tool to convert old 3d data from a program and convert it into a new format.
The problem i have is, the old program is storring the scale/rotation in a 3x3 matrix and i have no experiance with this kind of stuff.

For testing i have created an object only with scale 0.5 and saved it. It has the matrix

0.5, 0.0, 0.0

0.0, 0.5, 0.0

0.0, 0.0, 0.5

These are the scales for all 3 axis

Then i changed the object to have only rotations xyz of 45 degrees and a scale of 1 and got this matrix

0.5, -0.146447, 0.853553

0.5, 0.853553, -0.146447

-0.707107, 0.5, 0.5

I was able to convert this to the correct angles

Now i come to my showstopper: i changed the object to have a scale of 0.5 and a rotation of 45 degrees. The new matrix somehow combined both values into one matrix:

0.25, -0.0732233, 0.426777

0.25, 0.426777, -0.0732233

-0.353553, 0.25, 0.25

Basically the vales are the half of the secound matrix.
Currently im not able to figure out how to get the scale and the rotation out of this matrix, basically seperate them from each other. So if someone has an idea how this has to be done it world be great.

Answer (score 1):

The determinant of the matrix expresses the factor by which volumes increase. If you're matrix preserves angles, then that determinant must be the third power of the scale factor. Take the cube root and you get the scale factor.

Divide all elements of the matrix by that factor and you should end up with a pure rotation, or mathematically speaking an orthogonal matrix. Wikipedia has a good [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions) on how to convert between that and various other formalisms.